# Trouble with Conditional Statement in JavaScript - 'else' Not Executing as Expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function in global state manager:

```
 async function addFlashcard(flashcard) {
    try {
      console.log('working')
      const response = await axios.post('/addFlashcard', flashcard)
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log('finished successfully')
      return response
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('couldnt add question')
      console.log(error)
    }
```

then i call it in component:

```
  const response = await globalStore.addFlashcard(flashcard)

  if (response.status === 200) {
    makeAToast('Added! Thank you', 'success')
  } else {
    makeAToast('Something went wrong', 'error')
  }
```

and data that i send are validated on the server; if i send the proper data, and the status code is 200, i get the toast;
if i send a invalid data on purpose, to see if a makeAToast works, it doesnt work;

so i send a bad request, i get:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/addFlashcard 500 (Internal Server Error)
couldnt add question
```

but the

```
 makeAToast('Something went wrong', 'error')
```

doesnt work. Why else statement is working?

Comment: You don't return anything in the `catch` block. So there's no `response.status` property because `response` is undefined. Aren't you getting an error from that?

Comment: but anyway, the statusCode isnt 200. how to return response in catch if i cant use response in catch block that is defined in try block

Comment: Use conditional chaining: `if (response?.status == 200)`

Comment: thanks! it works! but why my code didnt work in first place, i still want to understand that

Comment: When Axios gets an error, you go into the `catch` block. It doesn't have a `return` statement, so it's returning `undefined`. You can't access properties of `undefined`, so it gets an error when it tries to test `response.status`.

Comment: You should have gotten an  error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')`

Comment: It might be better to put the `try/catch` in the code that calls `addFlashCard()` instead of in the function.

Comment: thanks for explanation! but stil, the if statement check if status Code is 200, the axios return undefined so it should go to else statemnt anyway; but thanks sir, you provided not only solution but also explanation, 

Comment: It doesn't go into the else because it stops when it gets this error.

Comment: It can be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76240972/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-axios-from-throwing-an-error-when-the-response-code-is But the common way is to handle an error in a caller with try-catch.

Comment: yes but I didnt understand why else statement ist executed in first place..